# Solving the integral $\int\limits^{\infty}_{1}\frac{x-\sqrt{\lfloor x^2\rfloor}}{x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, summation, improper-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> This problem was just for fun

Here was what I managed to come up with:

1. The integral is approximately equal to $0.242070053984$.
2. The integral equals

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n+1}}\frac{x-\sqrt{n}}{x}dx$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n+1}}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{x}\right)dx$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n}\int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n+1}}\frac{1}{x}dx\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n}\ln\left(\sqrt{n+1}\right)+\sqrt{n}\ln\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\right)$$

I found many ways to manipulate this summation but I could not figure out whether any of them actually would make it easier to solve. For example, $\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(e^{\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}-1}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)$ is not any easier to solve (I think).

And before you ask: No, I do not know whether or not this is actually solvable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just had a new idea of a way to solve it. I will add it to the post when I am done trying it.

Comment: Your question is clearly equivalent to evaluating $\lim_{k \to \infty} 1-\sqrt{k+1} + \tfrac 12 \sum_{n=1}^k \sqrt{n} \log\left(\tfrac{n}{n+1}\right)$, but it's not obvious to me that this sum has a closed form. Perhaps a clever summation by parts could make it telescope?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I think you mean $-1+\sqrt{k+1}+\cdots$?

Comment: Yes, ofc. Thanks @aschepler

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen That was my idea but I was struggling with the second half. WolframAlpha says $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\sqrt{n}\ln\left(n\right)=\zeta^{1,0}\left(-\frac{1}{2},x+1\right)-\zeta'\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ but it is not evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\sqrt{n}\ln\left(n+1\right)$

Comment: This is probably not useful, but as an alternative, you can let $x = \sqrt{u}$ then transform the improper integral into an infinite series of definite integrals over $(n, n+1)$. You would get the same answer as in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n}\log\left(\sqrt{n+1}\right)+\sqrt{n}\log\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$$ Using Taylor series
$$a_n=\frac 18 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\,\frac {\alpha_n}{\beta_n}\, n^{- \frac {2k+1} 2}$$ where the $\alpha_n$ form sequence $A120778$ in $OEIS$ and the first $\beta_n$ form the (unknown) sequence
$$\{1,6,16,160,384,1792,4096,73728,163840,720896,1572864,13631488,\cdots\}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\frac 18 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\,\frac {\alpha_n}{\beta_n}\,\, \zeta \left(\frac{2k+1}{2} \right)$$

Computing the partial sums (up to $p$) shows a very slow convergence
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \sum_{n=1}^p a_n\\
 100 & 0.239326 \\
 200 & 0.240460 \\
 300 & 0.240849 \\
 400 & 0.241046 \\
 500 & 0.241165 \\
 600 & 0.241245 \\
 700 & 0.241302 \\
 800 & 0.241345 \\
 900 & 0.241379 \\
 1000 & 0.241406 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using Euler-MacLaurin summation formula
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=C-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{19}{36 n}+\frac{49}{120 n^2}-\frac{6889}{20160 n^3}+\frac{5051}{17280 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right) \right)$$ for a suitable constant $C$.

For this level of expansion
$$C=\frac{220266777361440211}{259003680974438400}-\frac{1262147487374869}{738871813865472 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi }{6}+\frac{9293445205   \log (2)}{90194313216}$$

Comment: I'm impressed. Great answer!

Comment: @DylanLevine. Don't be ! You did the job and I tried to continue. I think that there could be other ways to do it. Still thinking. Cheers :-)